Aiogramm. ошибка Run polling for bot
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

from os import getenv
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F, types, html
from aiogram.client.default import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message


from My_bot.app.handlers import router

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token='тут был токен')
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_router(router)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
    await updater.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)


Ошибка выходит у меня, не понимаю откуда она, подскажите, пожалуйста. Запускаю с ноута

NFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Start polling
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher:Run polling for bot @itineraryBusBot id=8073880205 - 'itinerary_BOT'
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher:Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher:Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = 8073880205)


По вашему токену уже есть запущенный тг бот, 2 бота не могут одновременно получать обновления от телеграм по одному и тому же токену

@Medvedev спасибо, я просто не понимаю как я его запускать то могу еще раз, если в файлы другие не импортирую. И подскажите, может его тогда как то проверять перед запуском( что не запущены 2)? или закрывать принудительно?

Вариантов может быть множество, поэтому начните с простого и создайте новый токен для тг бота, вставьте его в код и запустите, и смотрите за реакцией.
